# Reconstruct a set of enumerations from the set of its restrictions to smaller domains

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\alpha_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal.

Let $U$ be the set of all $\alpha_1$-long enumerations of $\alpha_1$ (equivalently: $U$ is the set of bijections $\alpha_1 \to
\alpha_1$).

Let $S\subseteq U$ be an unknown subset of $U$.  Thus, $S$ is a set of
sequences ... but we don't know what it is.

Given a countable subset $A\subseteq\alpha_1$, write $S|_A$ for the
set of restrictions of elements of $S$, to $A$.  Thus,
$S|_A = \{ u|_A \mid u\in S\}$
where $u|_A$ is obtained in the natural way by restricting the
uncountable sequence $u\in U$ to the indexes $A$ to obtain a countable subsequence $u|_A$.

Suppose we are given
$$
F_S=\{ (A, S|_A) \mid  \text{all countable }A\subseteq \alpha_1 \}.
$$
Thus, we are given the function $F_S$ that if given a countable
$A\subseteq\alpha_1$, will tell us the restriction of $S$ to $A$.

Can we reconstruct what $S$ was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. For instance, let $\operatorname{id}$ be the identity bijection of $\alpha_1$. Then $F_U=F_{U\setminus \operatorname{id}}$, because each bijection between countable subsets of $\alpha_1$ can be extended to a non-identity bijection of $\alpha_1$. In particular, $U|_A= (U\setminus \operatorname{id})|_A $ for each countable subset $A$ of $\alpha_1$.

Comment: Excellent example.  Thank you.